# Hover text not moving relative to element when scrolled

Tags: html, css

For "foo, bar, baz, qux" in the snippet below, the hovered text is directly under the element and it correct. However, after I scroll down and then hover over an element the text is no longer under the text and goes outside the main-container. How can I ammend this so that the hovered text would remain inside the main-container and also directly under the text like it is in "foo, bar, baz, qux"?

```css
#main-container {
   max-height: 80px;
   overflow-y: scroll; 
   display: inline-block;
}
.hastooltip {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hastooltip:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
  color: black;
}


.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: none;
  background: #afeafe;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
    <div id="text-container">
        <span class="hastooltip">
          <div id="first">foo</div>
          <span class="tooltip">a</span>
        </span>
        <span class="hastooltip">
          <div id="second">bar</div>
          <span class="tooltip">b</span>
        </span>
        <span class="hastooltip">
          <div id="third">baz</div>
          <span class="tooltip">c</span>
        </span>
        <span class="hastooltip">
          <div id="fourth">qux</div>
          <span class="tooltip">d</span>
        </span>
        <span class="hastooltip">
          <div id="fifth">quux</div>
          <span class="tooltip">e</span>
        </span>
        <span class="hastooltip">
          <div id="sixth">corge</div>
          <span class="tooltip">f</span>
        </span>            
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign `position: relative;` to its parent element.

See the following code snippet:

```css
#main-container {
  max-height: 80px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hastooltip {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative
}

.hastooltip:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
  color: black;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: none;
  background: #afeafe;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
  <div id="text-container">
    <span class="hastooltip">
          <div id="first">foo</div>
          <span class="tooltip">a</span>
    </span>
    <span class="hastooltip">
          <div id="second">bar</div>
          <span class="tooltip">b</span>
    </span>
    <span class="hastooltip">
          <div id="third">baz</div>
          <span class="tooltip">c</span>
    </span>
    <span class="hastooltip">
          <div id="fourth">qux</div>
          <span class="tooltip">d</span>
    </span>
    <span class="hastooltip">
          <div id="fifth">quux</div>
          <span class="tooltip">e</span>
    </span>
    <span class="hastooltip">
          <div id="sixth">corge</div>
          <span class="tooltip">f</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.hastooltip {
  cursor: pointer;
position:relative;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Set the position to `relative` to its parent `.hastooltip`. So the absolute position stops at `position: relative;`.